# Chrome extension icon in search result

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I recently published a [chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/wiki-preview/keodbghcggpcaaihokbhmeehadnkemgc) in the webstore.

I provided all requires icons and images, but when I search my extension in the store, in the result page I get the worst pixelized icon.

Which icon/image is used in the search results page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The search results page actually uses the "small tile image", scaled down.

The [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/images) mentions it as required, but it's optional in the publishing UI; if not provided, a scaled-up 128x128 icon is used as far as I can tell.

Comment: I did provide all the promotional tile images (in particular the "Small tile - 440x280")in the developer dashboard, but it still scales up one of my icons. Do you have any idea why is that so?

Comment: Was the promo image accepted? It goes through manual review.

Comment: If it's manual review then I might need to wait. I uploaded my extension few hours ago.